# Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$rows in index.php

Tags: php, class, oop, object, mysqli

I'm trying to create MySQLi driver from some opensource for a new web application and can't get past an undefined property notice.

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$rows in index.php
```

The relevant lines from index.php

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."setting WHERE store_id='".(int)$config->get('config_store_id')."' ORDER BY store_id ASC");

foreach($query->rows as $setting) {

if(!$setting['serialized']) {
    $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
} else {
    $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
}
}
```

And my mysqli controller

```
class MySQLii {
private $link;

public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if(!$this->link = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)) {
        trigger_error('Could not make a MySQLi database link using '.$username.'@'.$hostname);
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_query($this->link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($this->link, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysqli_query($this->link, "SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
    mysqli_query($this->link, "SET SQL_MODE = ''");
}

public function query($sql) {
    if($this->link) {
        $resource = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);        

        if($resource) {
            if($resource instanceof mysqli_result) {
                $i=0;
                $data = array();
                while($result=$resource->fetch_object()) {
                    $data[$i]=$result;
                    $i++;
                }

                $result->close();

                $query = new stdClass();
                $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                $query->rows = $data;
                $query->num_rows = $i;
                unset($data);
                return $query;
            } else { return true; }
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: '.mysqli_error($this->link).'<br>Error No: '.mysqli_errno($this->link).'<br>'.$sql);
            exit();
        }
    } 
}
```

and the db controller that loads the appropriate driver based on config settings, in this case the mysqli driver...

```
class DB {
private $driver;

public function __construct($driver, $hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if(file_exists(DIR_DATABASE.$driver.'.php')) {
        require_once(DIR_DATABASE.$driver.'.php');
    } else {
        trigger_error('Could not load database file '.$driver.'.');
        exit();
    }

    $this->driver = new $driver($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
}

public function query($sql) {
    return $this->driver->query($sql);
}

public function escape($value) {
    return $this->driver->escape($value);
}

public function countAffected() {
    return $this->driver->countAffected();
}

public function getLastId() {
    return $this->driver->getLastId();
}
}
```

Is there a reason that my index.php isn't recognizing the stdClass and telling me that $query->rows isn't a property? Incidentally, this code (nearly identical) with mysql instead of mysqli works just fine!

Comment: Post more of `index.php` please.  `$query` is not the object you expect it to be, it would seem. Instead of the `stdClass` you expect to have been returned from `MySQLii::query()`, it looks to be a `mysqli_result` object...  We need to see where that `$query` variable is set..

Comment: Thanks Michael. I added that above. Also $db is loaded from a database controller that simply points to the mysqli controller file when mysqli is selected as the driver

Comment: Something about that database controller is incorrect then. Instead of `$db` being your custom `MySQLii` class, it is probably just a plain `mysqli` object, on which the `query()` call succeeds and returns a `mysqli_result`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I just added the db class too, so when I want to use mysql (set in a config.php file), it works beautifully with no errors other than mysql is deprecated blah blah blah. $db is set in the index.php file with

    $db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

I'm not too worried about that because I can turn off the notices. However, using almost identical structure in the mysqli class except for the minor differences of mysqli functions, it's breaks even though I'm setting up query as a stdClass in the mysqlii class.

Comment: You call `new $driver(...)` which means you're probably passing `'mysqli'` as the `$driver` and ending up with a plain `mysqli` object (since that's what your `DB` class does). If you want to use your custom class wrapper, looks like you need to pass `$driver = 'MySQLii'` so your `DB` class instantiates `new MySQLii()`, your wrapper.

Comment: passing mysqli tells the DB class to load the mysqli.php file which contains the class 'MySQLii' :-/

Comment: I understand that's your intent, but look at the code.  Though the file `DIR_DATABASE/mysqli.php` may define the class `MySQLii` and be correctly included, you still call `new $driver()` and the variable `$driver` contains `'mysqli'`.  So you correctly load the class file you intend to load but still instantiate a plain `mysqli` object because the file has a different name than the class it defines. If you rename the flie from `mysqli.php` to `mysqlii.php` it may just work exactly as you have everything else.